# UWP and nested json objects

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON code in a c# applicatie. I use the DataContractJsonSerializer class to do this. All works fine, until I get  nested jsonobjects,

I recieve the following json from an external API:

```
[{"name":"Beeldscherm","json":"{\"onHomeEnter\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487166732440},\"onHomeExit\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":120,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487163669388},\"onRoomEnter\":{\"state\":1,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1},\"onRoomExit\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":120,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1},\"onNear\":{\"state\":1,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487164911729},\"onAway\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":2,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487164909184}}","id":"58a44fa04f40b016004ffca2","sphereId":"58a44c0a4f40b016004ffc9d","createdAt":"2017-02-15T13:52:12.783Z","updatedAt":"2017-02-15T12:55:05.332Z"}]
```

Which I edit with the following code:

```
responJsonText = responJsonText.Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"", "}");
```

and it then looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Beeldscherm","json":{"onHomeEnter":{"state":0,"delay":0,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1487166732440},"onHomeExit":{"state":0,"delay":120,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1487163669388},"onRoomEnter":{"state":1,"delay":0,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1},"onRoomExit":{"state":0,"delay":120,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1},"onNear":{"state":1,"delay":0,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1487164911729},"onAway":{"state":0,"delay":2,"fadeTime":0,"active":false,"updatedAt":1487164909184}},"id":"58a44fa04f40b016004ffca2","sphereId":"58a44c0a4f40b016004ffc9d","createdAt":"2017-02-15T13:52:12.783Z","updatedAt":"2017-02-15T12:55:05.332Z"}]
```

and try to parse this using the following classes:

```
[DataContract]
class Appliance
{
    [DataMember]
    public String name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceJson json { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String sphereId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String createdAt { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String updatedAt { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class ApplianceJson
{
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onHomeEnter { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onHomeExit { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onRoomEnter { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onRoomExit { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onNear { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ApplianceEvents onAway { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class ApplianceEvents
{
    [DataMember]
    public int state { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int delay { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool active { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int updatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code for the deserialization:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Appliance>));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responJsonText));
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

Does anybody see something that is wrong and how I could fix it?

*Update*
I checked the json string and its correct now, I've put the correct version in the question

*Update 2*
added the original JSON

Comment: Your Json is not parsing. Try Online Json Parser and see if you are receiving Proper Json.

Comment: You should look to see if there is an inner exception that has more detail.

Comment: @AVKNaidu there indeed was something wrong with the json, this was because the API that gave the JSON back turned the json element inside the json object in a string and I only removed the \ and not " surrounding the object, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the actual json that you are receiving ? Before you stripping out anything?

Comment: @crashmstr the error doesn't stop the execution and with adding a break point I can't see the inner exception. Not sure how else I could do it

Comment: If you turn on break on exception, that would possibly help. You could also try/catch and add some logging.

Comment: @AVKNaidu I've added the actual json and the code I use to change it

Comment: @crashmstr thanks for your help, turning on break on exception gave me the warning I needed. The problem was the updatedAt in the ApplianceEvents, the number for this was to long. So changing this to type String solved the problem

Comment: if you notice the Original Json, You can see `"` is not `\"` but if you go deep into json, the Json Node itself has `"` as `\"`. So i cleaned up all `\"` first and then again replaced `"` with `\"` Used Newtonsoft Json and then it parsed successfully. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you notice the Original Json, You can see `"` is not `\"` but if you go deep into json, the Json Node itself has `"` as `\"`. So i cleaned up all `\"` first and then again replaced `"` with `\"` Used Newtonsoft Json and then it parsed successfully. See my answer.

Using [This](http://json2csharp.com)  Site and your JsonString, Below are the proper Json Class Structure that I created.

```
public class Appliance
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Json json { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sphereId { get; set; }
    public string createdAt { get; set; }
    public string updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnHomeEnter
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public long updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnHomeExit
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public long updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnRoomEnter
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public int updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnRoomExit
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public int updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnNear
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public long updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class OnAway
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int delay { get; set; }
    public int fadeTime { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public long updatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class Json
{
    public OnHomeEnter onHomeEnter { get; set; }
    public OnHomeExit onHomeExit { get; set; }
    public OnRoomEnter onRoomEnter { get; set; }
    public OnRoomExit onRoomExit { get; set; }
    public OnNear onNear { get; set; }
    public OnAway onAway { get; set; }
}
```

Once Done, I used [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)
  to Parse the JsonString to `Appliance` Object

Below is the Final Json String and Parser.

```
"[{\"name\":\"Beeldscherm\",\"json\":{\"onHomeEnter\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487166732440},\"onHomeExit\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":120,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487163669388},\"onRoomEnter\":{\"state\":1,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1},\"onRoomExit\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":120,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1},\"onNear\":{\"state\":1,\"delay\":0,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487164911729},\"onAway\":{\"state\":0,\"delay\":2,\"fadeTime\":0,\"active\":false,\"updatedAt\":1487164909184}},\"id\":\"58a44fa04f40b016004ffca2\",\"sphereId\":\"58a44c0a4f40b016004ffc9d\",\"createdAt\":\"2017 - 02 - 15T13: 52:12.783Z\",\"updatedAt\":\"2017 - 02 - 15T12: 55:05.332Z\"}]";
```

And Below is how I was able to successfully Parse Json.

```
List<Appliance> appJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Appliance>>(JsonData);
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I found the answer just before you posted the answer, it wasn't just the \"(which I already removed) but also the " around the json block. After replacing "{ with { and }" with } it worked. But thanks for looking into it.